# Upgrade cluster sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering, upgrade

How can I upgrade SQL Server cluster 2012 to SQL Server 2014? Version – Standard. We have 2 nodes and 2 instances on each node. Have you manuals for upgrade 2 instances on cluster SQL Server 2014

We have 2 nodes (node1 and node2) and 2 instances(inst1 and inst2). I started to upgrade on passive node2 instance inst1. After this SQL don't allow to upgrade instance inst2 on node2.

If I try upgrade inst2 then SQL show message

> upgrade instance is pending.

Therefore I try to upgrade node1 instance inst1. After this I upgrade instance inst2 on each nodes similarly. But system don't allow and show message “upgrade instance is pending”. Why? Can you explain me?